# Multiple extra source directories in Maven [Compile Error] in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

i'm working on a "complex"/"well-structured" Maven Project, and in particular i'm working on a single internal Module of the project. I'm against a COMPILE ERROR because it seems that it doesn't find the Java Classes from an external source already linked from the Menu (right-clicking on the project) ->Build Path->Link Source.
This is a bunch of essential errors taken from the Console when i Run-> mvn : compile

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project optimizer: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/Ste/Desktop/eclip/workspace/planner/src/main/java/eu/planner/Module.java:[24,19] package jmetal.core does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Ste/Desktop/eclip/workspace/planner/src/main/java/eu/planner/Module.java:[35,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Variable
[ERROR] /Users/Ste/Desktop/eclip/workspace/planner/src/main/java/eu/planner/Module.java:[39,11] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Problem
[ERROR] location: class eu.planner.Module
[INFO] 100 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 45.090 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-02T10:46:45+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/219M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project optimizer: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/Ste/Desktop/eclip/workspace/planner/src/main/java/eu/planner/heuristics/SVariable.java:[234,9] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /Users/Ste/Desktop/eclip/workspace/planner/src/main/java/eu/planner/heuristics/SVariable.java:[237,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable super
[ERROR] location: class eu.planner.heuristics.SVariable
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Adding the -X it shows the DEBUG, but nothing strange. It just add at the end this information:

```
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project optimizer: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:858)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I also tried to add in the POM of the Module i'm working on, this build helper taken from here [http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html](http://Build%20Helper%20Maven) (without success):

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals><goal>add-source</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>/Users/Ste/Desktop/externalFolderWithJavaClasses<source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Where `plugin` element is in `/project/build/plugins` and NOT in `/project/build/pluginManagement/plugins`.

I checked my `target/classes` folder of the project and it is empty.

I'm not importing files from any other projects. Just linked a folder from my filesystem.
The path you see in the screenshot is different from what you see in Compile Error because at the beginning i thought to not show my real path.
Here 2 Screenshot:

[image: Source Folder View inside my Project with its content]

[image: Java Build Path (the Project Tab is empty, no projects linked)]

Does anyone understand what is wrong? Thank you so much

P.S. I'm using a Mac OS X x64, Eclipse Luna, and the project is Pulled from a GitHub repository if for someone this information is fundamental.

Comment: Is your project importing files from any other project, because that is the reason why you have got mojo failure Exception

Comment: I added 2 screenshots in order to clarify my situation. However, i'm not importing files from any other project. The path you see in the screenshot is different from what you see in Compile Error because at the beginning i thought to not show my real path.

Comment: I removed the linked source, and re-added it. The compile Error is gone, the `target/classes` are now full of .class files (related to source folder as well). Why is it working just doing this and without any strange configuration in POM as Build-Maven-Helper suggests (that was the best solution for many other users)? I will write as best answer of my problem later, only if my new problem, which is came out after the latter, will be solved. New problem: I have 2 Java Test Class in src/test/java, but only one of these is recognized in a mvn:test. I'm gonna create a new related Question for that

Answer (score 0):

Your problem makes sense in a way. Originally, you added a source folder to your project through Eclipse, but not through maven. And when you tried to compile your maven sources, maven barfed since it couldn't find the folder you added through Eclipse.

It's a little surprising that you're still getting the same error when you use the build-helper-maven-plugin. Since that is the proper way of adding extra source folders.  I think you just need to run `mvn clean verify` and all should be good again.

Inside of Eclipse, make sure to run Maven -> Update project... and your project should also have the proper source folders on it.

Comment: I don't know why but i fixed that just by removing and adding again the source folder not in the proper way as you mentioned (through Eclipse). That's quite strange that even if not having the Build-Maven-Helper plugin it worked. Anyway i don't know if it would be a good idea write my previous comment as Answer so that the Best one. What do you think? By the way, I will use your answer as a try if i find some problem related. Thank you anyway